# Error with flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2 for ios #11394

Tags: flutter

**Error**
!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Stripe":
In Podfile:
stripe_ios (from `.symlinks/plugins/stripe_ios/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Stripe (~> 22.3.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Stripe (~> 22.3.0)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
  ====================================================================

[My Code](https://github.com/NavneetTechlene/stripeExample%60)(`https://github.com/NavneetTechlene/stripeExample`)

1.) using
Xcode Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)
flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2
Flutter 3.0.1• channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

2.) Build for Android success but for iphone

3.) arch -x86_64 pod install  with flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2 above error and with # flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2  in pubspec.yaml i can make ios ipa

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i just add " flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2" this in pubspec.yaml and try to install in iphone not able to do so got error part from above the mycode part not able to do so pod install

Comment: I'm not sure but have you added the merchantId and the  pay certificat?  https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#csr

Answer (score 25):

I have faced similar issue with `flutter_stripe: ^3.0.2` on `Flutter 3.0.1` cocoa pods couldn't install.

Change to ios platform 13 in Podfile

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Then can run pod install or run app. it worked for me.

Comment: You might also need to delete the Podfile.lock and re-run `pod install --repo-update` if the above steps don't work

Answer (score 4):

I Got Similar issue as Suggested By @Dr_Usman I have changed `IOS Version to 13` but It's not help me. So If its not working then Change IOS Version to 13 and then `delete Podfile.lock` then `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

you can use flutter_stripe 3.2.0 with ios 12+. it works purely